# Regex: Find all lines starting with a specific tag and ending with a different tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to Find all lines starting with a specific tag and ending with a different tag. For example:

`<p class="amigo">My mother is at home.<br>`

tried a regex, but doesn't work to good, because the selection does not stop at `<br>`, it selects all after it, if I have more tags like this:  `.*<p class="amigo">(?s)(.*)<br>*$`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the wildcard not greedy:

```
<p class="amigo">(?s)(.*?)<br>
//               here __^
```

---

Edit according to comment:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="amigo">(?:(?!</?p).)*<br>`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="amigo">   # literally
(?:                 # start non capture group
    (?!</?p)        # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "<p" or "</p"
    .               # 1 anycharacter
)*                  # end group, may appear 0 or more times
<br>                # literally
```

[image]

Comment: not quite, if I have something like this, doesn't work, it selects all tags/lines. 

`<p class="amigo">My mother is at home.</p>`

`<p class="amigo">My mother is at home.</p>`

`<p class="amigo">My mother is at home.<br>`

Comment: @JustMe: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

also, I find another answer:

`<p class="amigo">(?s)(?-s)(.*)<br>*$`

or

`<p class="amigo">(?-s)(.*)<br>*$`

Comment: `(?s)` means "dot matches newline" and `(?-s)` nmeans the opposite "dot doesn't match newline. So, `(?s)(?-s)` is the same that `(?-s)` for Notepad++ it is the same that  "Uncheck dot matches newline". (un)check it depending if you want to match linebreak within the 2 tags. `>*$` means 0 or more `>` before end of line. It is useless here.

Comment: I didn't mention in my regex the option "dot match newline". I just test it, and works. Of course, you gave me an idea, so you get my vote. Test my regex, you will see that is working, even if something may seem strange :)

Comment: Of course it works, I've just given you some tricks to get your regex more efficient and simpler.

Comment: hello, yes. But what exactly means "match new lines" ?

Comment: It means that `.` matches newline (`\r`,`\n`). The default behaviour is `.` doesn't match newline.

Comment: so it replace the \r or \n . Now I understand. Thanks.